# Tag Manager Variable from a parent of click element (toggle)

Tags: css-selectors, google-tag-manager

Here is the structure of the toggle:

```
<div data-id="thisIsTheID" class="abc">
  <div class="edf">
    <button value="false"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trigger only works with click >> all elements >> click classes contains edf. I tried click element matches css selector

- div.abc
- div.abc *
- div.abc button

but none will work as trigger.

However, I want the data-id as variable in Google Tag Manager in order to differentiate between different toggles.

How do I create a trigger that works and how do I get the variable?

Here the actual code and debugger view:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the div.abc * , div.abc should work. Can you screenshot the click element in the preview? We want to see which click element that Google Tag Manager captured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making a custom JS variable like so:

```
function(){
    return {{Click Element}}.parentElement.getAttribute("data-test-id");
}
```

It should return the value of your attribute on click.

But the classes look auto-generated. They feel like they can and will change on cache refresh or on front-end builds. I would try to use selectors like `div[data-test-id] *` or even `div[data-test-id=isAgePolicy] *`

Comment: Thanks, it did the trick :-). And I changed the selectors as well.

Comment: Unfortenately, I noticed, that it only works for like 95% of all clicks. With some clicks (on elments that formerly and later will work) it does not get the "data-test-id". Any clue why?

Comment: because 5% of clicks are lended on something else, like on a span or similar. You should investigate the clicks that don't work, but should. You should pay attention to what element is being clicked on misclicks. You do it by looking at the {{Click Element}} variable in the debugger.