# Tag Manager js variable with condition

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

This is a follow up of [Tag Manager Variable from a parent of click element (toggle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370386/tag-manager-variable-from-a-parent-of-click-element-toggle)

I want to fire a GA4 event on a toggle click where the code is this:
[image][image]

I had to change the css - Selector to `div[data-test-id^="is"],div[data-test-id^="is"] *` because I noticed that only clicks right on the button worked. If you click on the untoggled part it would set the toggle but wouldn't fire the event.

So I had to adapt the js variable for the toggles name as well but that didn't work:

```js
function(){
  var dataTestID; 
  if({{Click Element}}.parentElement.getAttribute("data-test-id") == null)
  {dataTestID = {{Click Element}}.getAttribute("data-test-id")
;}
 dataTestID = {{Click Element}}.parentElement.getAttribute("data-test-id");

return dataTestID;
}
```

Could you identify the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are having problem like

```html
<div class='a' data-test-id="test">
  <div class='b'>
    <button class='c'></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So if you click the div with class=b, it will work because its parent element is div.a with data-test-id attribute.

But if you click the button element it won't work because its parent element is div.b?

In this case you can change the code parent to closest()

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

This might help the code to get the `data-test-id` when the your click div.b or button

Answer (score 1):

Based on Darrelwan's suggestion I changed it to

```
function(){
  var e = {{Click Element}};
  var closestData = e.closest('[data-test-id]');
  return closestData.dataset.testId;
}
```

It works.